# Inserte hey value of multidimensional array inside another multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have this two array:

Array1

```
[
{"month":"2020-09","Channel 1":1153,"Channel 2":3402,"Channel 3":31,"Channel 4":608,"Channel 5":90,"Channel 6":2684,"Channel 7":1677,"Channel 8":5},
{"month":"2020-10","Channel 2":1452,"Channel 3":4206,"Channel 6":1,"Channel 8":1859},
{"month":"2020-11","Channel 1":2627,"Channel 2":4575,"Channel 4":30,"Channel 5":637,"Channel 7":156}
]
```

Array2

```
[
{"month":"2020-09","totalMonth":9046},
{"month":"2020-10","totalMonth":7518},
{"month":"2020-11","totalMonth":8025}
]
```

I need `totalMonth => Value` of Array2 to be inserted into Array1 for each respective month and get this structure of Array1:

Array1

```
[
{"month":"2020-09","Channel 1":1153,"Channel 2":3402,"Channel 3":31,"Channel 4":608,"Channel 5":90,"Channel 6":2684,"Channel 7":1677,"Channel 8":5,"totalMonth":9046},
{"month":"2020-10","Channel 2":1452,"Channel 3":4206,"Channel 6":1,"Channel 8":1859,"totalMonth":7518},
{"month":"2020-11","Channel 1":2627,"Channel 2":4575,"Channel 4":30,"Channel 5":637,"Channel 7":156,"totalMonth":8025}
]
```

i tried multiple ways iterating the array but to no avail. Can you suggest me a solution please?

Comment: "_i tried multiple ways iterating the array but to no avail_" Please show us at least one of those efforts. What didn't work? Wrong values? Blank page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved Thanks Dennis. but to correct the error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

I wrote the code like this:

```
foreach ($r2 as $key2 => $value2)
{
    foreach ($r1 as $key1 => $value1)
    {
        if ($value2->month === $r1[$key1]['month'])
            $r1[$key1]["totalMonth"] = $value2->totalMonth;
    }
}
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If `$r1` and `$r2` are the first two arrays respectively, try

```
foreach ($r1 as $key1 => $value1)
{
    foreach ($r2 as $key2 => $value2)
    {
        if ($r1[$key1]->month === $r2[$key2]->month)
            $r1[$key1]->totalMonth = $r2[$key2]->totalMonth;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns an errors: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array for line "if ($r1[$key1]['month'] === $r2[$key2]['month'])"

Comment: I have changed my code to use object notation.  Let me know if that works.